# Pytest not working. Says term "pytest" not recognized

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have two files. One with the code to be tested and another file with the testing code. When I enter pytest in the testing files terminal I get an error that pytest is not recognized

What I entered in VS code terminal:

```
pytest
```

The error I get:

```
The term 'pytest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

More detail:
I installed `pip` and then `pytest`. In my settings in VS code, I enabled pytest testing and it says the path to pytest is simply pytest.

Comment: The `pytest` executable program was installed somewhere in your home directory.  On Linux it is usually `~/.local/bin/`. I don't know what the exact Windows directory is, but wherever it is, you should add that directory to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I messed around in the settings and now the testing feature on VSCode is working and tells me if the test is working or not however I cant get the test to execute from the terminal itself. I still get the pytest not recognized